# is there any way to minimize the code, as I have multiple textfields on different controllers. can I could code only once and use it

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Objective C** is there any way to minimize the code, as I have multiple textfields on different controllers.

Can I code only once and use it.
As I want to make the text field rectangular, show the image in the left side of the **UITextFiled**.

Please help if possible.
coding several time increases the size bytes of code and consumes time to, codes seems too much bulky too.

Comment: yes, create a subclass of UITextfield that will set up the textfield how you want it, then just use your class instead of the normal UITextfield

Comment: This is the main OOP feature: inheritance, child, parent classes, etc. :)

Comment: Can any one help me with the any proper pre designed custom class for text field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a sub-class of `UITextField` and re-use it in the proj.

**YourBaseTxtField.h**

```
@interface YourBaseTxtField : UITextField 

// Take required properties 
@end
```

**YourBaseTxtField.m**

```
@interface YourBaseTxtField () 

@end

@implementation YourBaseTxtField
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        //  Do customization
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

    }
 return self;
}
```

In your VCs

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    self.textField = [[YourBaseTxtField alloc] init];
    self.textField.delegate = self;
    self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault
}
// Use text field delegates
```

Thanks

Comment: - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        //  Do customization
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

    }
 return self;
}

Comment: @aavirya, initWithCoder is used to loading the nib file. And you can't modify the method. You can use "awakeFromNib" or "initWithNibName:bundle" for customisation.  For clear understanding  https://www.quora.com/Cocoa-API-What-is-the-difference-between-initWithCoder-initWithNibName-and-awakeFromNib-1

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UITextField and use that. I don't remember Obj-C very well, but as I recall it's something like this in your .h file: `interface CustomTextField : UITextField`.